# Sharing State Between Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to make two components: App and Map. However when I try to make a new brand Map component and send the data from App to Map component, I cannot.

My App (default) component holds the data as a state. When I try to send this state to the Map component. It holds the data as a prop.

And of course If I don't separate them and write everything in App.js, everything works as I expected (markers shown on the map). But I want to control all states in the parent component.

Am I violating a fundamental React rule? How can I fix that?

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Map from "./Map";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      locations: [],
      markers: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(
      "correct_foursquare_api_url"
    )
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data =>
        data.response.venues.map(place => ({
          id: place.id,
          name: place.name,
          lat: place.location.lat,
          lng: place.location.lng
        }))
      )
      .then(locations => {
        this.setState({ locations });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
      <Map locations={this.state.locations} />
      </div>
      )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Map.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
/* global google */

class Map extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      locations: [],
      markers: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.callMap();
  }

  callMap() {
    window.initMap = this.initMap;
    loadJS(
      "api_url"
    );
  }

  // Map
  initMap = () => {
    const { locations, markers } = this.state;
    let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
      center: { lat: 59.4827293, lng: -83.1405355 },
      zoom: 13
    });

    // Markers
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      var title = locations[i].name;
      var position = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i].lat, locations[i].lng);
      var id = locations[i].id;
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: position,
        title: title,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        id: id
      });
      markers.push(marker);
    }
  };

  render() {
    return <div id="map" />;
  }
}

function loadJS(src) {
  var ref = window.document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  var script = window.document.createElement("script");
  script.src = src;
  script.async = true;
  ref.parentNode.insertBefore(script, ref);
}

export default Map;
```

Comment: You store your `locations` in `App`, but you also have `locations` in `Map` that you use on mount. Shouldn't you wait with rendering the `Map` component until the `locations` request is finished, and then use the `locations` props?

Comment: @Tholle how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You store your `locations` in the state of the `App` component, but you also have `locations` in state of the `Map` component that you use on mount.

You could instead wait with rendering the `Map` component until the `locations` request is finished, and then use the `locations` props in the `Map` component passed down from `App` instead.

**Example**

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      locations: [],
      markers: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("correct_foursquare_api_url")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        const locations = data.response.venues.map(place => ({
          id: place.id,
          name: place.name,
          lat: place.location.lat,
          lng: place.location.lng
        }));

        this.setState({ locations });
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { locations, markers } = this.state;

    if (locations.length === 0) {
      return null;
    }

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Map locations={locations} markers={markers} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Map extends Component {
  // ...

  initMap = () => {
    const { locations, markers } = this.props;

    // ...
  };

  // ...
}
```